# dead parents tree for debugging

Tags: linux, pid

```
$ ps
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
il       17626     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/bin/xdg-open file:///media/distrpart/Downloads/utorrent/test.png
```

I want to know who launched xdg-open, but the parent is dead.
Is there a way to not let processes die for a certain timeout?

Comment: Perhaps this answer from superuser might give you a hint. http://superuser.com/q/222912

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible. You would have to change (as in, programming) libc and init and you would break one of the fundamental rules in the unix process model, likely breaking many applications.

In short: don't do it :)